# If an electron is repelled by another electron how is it that we get an electric current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, charge, conductors

As we know that an electric current is a flow of electric charge in a circuit, and in electric circuits, the charge carriers are often electrons moving through a wire.

Now, since we know that like charges repel each other, then how do the electrons flow through a wire since they are like charges they should repel each other.

Comment: What does this have to do with the current? Presumably you also think there cannot be any electrons inside the conductor when no current flows, since they repel each other and should fly out of it, right? Conversely, if you have no problem with conductors existing in the absence of current, why does a problem arise when there is a current?

Comment: The water molecules in a hose also repel each other.  So we can't get water to flow through a hose?

Comment: @ACuriousMind No, I don't think there cannot be any electrons inside the conductor when no current flows.when no current flows the electrons are in a Random Motion inside the conductor.But, I want to know how they are held together inside a conductor since like charges repel one another.Please Help Me

Comment: In order to understand where current comes from you need to understand how a battery works. Essentially, the battery uses "chemical energy" (or uses the second law of thermodynamics, depending on your perspective) to make electrons accumulate on one end of the battery. Those ones then "push" their neighbors around the wire, if you like.

Comment: Have you read about Bohr's Model, Conduction in Semi-conductor, Energy Band gap ? Give them a read if not already known to you.

Answer (score 6):

They do indeed repel each other. But they are repelled from the point they are coming from *even stronger*.

- Imagine having two charged metal balls where one has half the charge of the other. When you connect them with a wire, will charges flow?

Yes. Sure, each individual electron feels a strong repulsion **from both** of the balls, since there already is an accumuation of electrons on both.

But the electron feels a **stronger** repulsion from the ball with **more** charge. So it will want to move towards the ball of lower charge. Just like a car being pushed from either end by two strong men will drift towards the weaker of them. The *total* force is relevant.

In fact, this is the working principle behind any charging mechanism. In order to accumulate a lot of charge in one point you just have to apply a *greater* force on the charge-carriers than the repulsion force they feel from that point. Charging a battery for instance requires the internal electrochemical forces to "push" electrons to the negative terminal *with a force that is greater* than the repulsion from that negative terminal.

Comment: you explained well. But I want to know more deeply what happens inside a conductor If each individual electron repel one another how do we get current.How do the electrons fow in one direction ?  how they are held together inside a conductor since like charges repel one another.

Comment: @Shashwatsingh I'm not sure what you mean by the electrons being "held together" inside the conductor. The electrons can be considered freely independent entities (idealised as little balls floating about, if you will). When a bunch of charge is added to one end, then the first electron will feel the repulsion. This electron will want to start drifting so it pushes on its neighbour along the conductor. Which in turn will push on *its* neighbour. Etc. At the speed of light, this electron push propagates through the conductor until all electrons are drifting.

Comment: I mean this only The electrons can be considered freely independent entities (idealised as little balls floating about, if you will).Steven you really explain very well.You mean to say that when a negative terminal is connected to a conductor the electrons in the conductor on the side of the negative terminal feel repulsion due to negative charges on the negative terminal now the very first electron feels repulsion we can say it is a valence electron so now this electron jumps to its neighbour atom.Steeven here I want to know that what  does this electron now do.

Comment: Does this electron repels another valence electron or the electrons of this neighbour atom repel this valence electron.Please help me

Comment: Does this electron repels another valence electron of this neighbour atom or the valence electrons of this neighbour atom repel this valence electron to move it further.Please help me

Comment: @Shashwatsingh The term *valence* typically belongs to ionic bonds (the "sharing" version of chemical bonds) which we don't have in metallic materials of typical conductors. In metallic bonds, it is better to think of the "free" electrons in an electron cloud, so to say, that can move freely through the metal. But anyways, yes, a good way of thinking about the electron motion is to imagine the them in fluctuating motions in random directions. Then a force pushes the first electron to drift sideways. This drift will push on the next electron, causing it to drift as well. And so on.

Comment: Steeven I am asking what happens after this when the very first electron feels repulsion we can say it is a valence electron so now this electron jumps to its neighbour atom.Steeven here I want to know that what does this electron now do Does this electron repels another valence electron of this neighbour atom or the valence electrons of this neighbour atom repel this valence electron to move it further.Please help me. Steeven please tell me here what happens after this ?

Comment: @Shashwatsingh We are not dealing with valence electrons here. The valence theory requires two non-equal atoms with matching valances that then are willing to share electrons. In metals we are dealing with the *same* atom throughout and can't really talk about valences. Rather, we can talk about free electrons in the conduction band that do not belong to a single atom or a single pair of atoms but to the "group" of many atoms as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

Electrons do repel each other but they also like to spread out. Quantum mechanics tells us that it costs a lot of energy to localize an electron in a small volume. These two tendencies compete. The quantum mechanical [Hubbard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model) is based on these two effects. It has two parameters: on-site repulsion and transfer energy (transfer Hamiltonian matrix element). Depending on the ratio of these you either get an insulator with localized electron orbitals or a conductor with delocalized orbitals. Localized orbitals describe electrons that are bound to a position are require an activation energy to become mobile.  Delocalized orbitals describe electrons that permanently move throughout the material at high energy and velocity. If all mobile electrons move in all directions with equal probability there is no current. When an electric field is applied a net drift velocity results and there is a current.

Electrons are also able to avoid one another to a large extent in 3D. This is why the [free electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) of conductors is not even so bad. In 1D they are not, which is why a true 1D system will always have localized orbitals and be an insulator.

Comment: Maybe you should make more explicit that the Hubbard model is a quantum mechanical model of a solid lattice. Electrons are quantum mechanical entities and the repulsion of like charges has to be dealt with quantum mechanical equations, not the simple coulomb interaction of macroscopic  like charges.

Answer (score 0):

The electrons in a conductor repel each other and are attracted by the nuclei. Both effects cancel out. The conductor is neutral, there is no excess of electrons.

So, without an applied emf their directions are random, and under an emf there is a net flow, breaking the symmetry of their momentum distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but you're imagination of current is wrong. You are imaging current or flow of electrons like number of balls flowing side by side to each other. However, that's not the case. If I'm not wrong, they're hoping from one atom to another. So if we take a snapshot of a moment when current is flowing it'll look exactly like a stationary material viz.with atoms huddled together and electrons orbiting them, and not just electrons flowing. They'll be at same distance from each other when flowing as they are when stationary (not under an emf).